# p:treeTable not display parent node in GUI

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable

primeface treenode is not printing properly in Xhtml, child value displayed in parent node. but in console printing value displayed correctly.

Here are my code :

Backing Bean :

```
public TreeNode getTreeData()
{

    lstTestProcessByRelease = testProcessBo.findAllTestProcessByReleaseGroupBy(getTestSuite(), getReleaseName());
    List<TestProcess> lstTestScenario = new ArrayList<TestProcess>();
    root1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Root",null);
    for(TestProcess tp : lstTestProcessByRelease)
    {

        TreeNode parent = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess(tp.getTestScenarioName(), tp.getTestCaseName(), tp.getTestCaseExecNo(), tp.getTestScenarioExecNo()),root1);
        System.out.println("============"+ tp.getTestScenarioName() +"=================");
        System.out.println("Scenario Name (ROWKEY) :"+ parent.getRowKey());
            lstTestScenario = testProcessBo.findAllTestCasesByTestScenarioName(tp.getTestSuite(), tp.getReleaseName(), tp.getTestScenarioName());
            TreeNode child =null;
            for(TestProcess tc : lstTestScenario)
            {

                child = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess(tc.getTestScenarioName(), tc.getTestCaseName(), tc.getTestCaseExecNo(), tc.getTestScenarioExecNo()),parent);
                System.out.println("TestCase (ROWKEY) :"+ child.getRowKey());
                System.out.println("Scenario Name :" + tc.getTestScenarioName());
                System.out.println("TestCases Name : " + tc.getTestCaseName());
                System.out.println("   TestScenario ExecNo :" + tc.getTestScenarioExecNo());
                System.out.println("      TestCase ExecNo :" + tc.getTestCaseExecNo());
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
    }


    return root1;
}
```

Xhtml file :

[[image: Output image]]

```
<p:treeTable value="#{testProcessBean.root1}" id="TestProcessID"
                        var="tree1" editable="true" editMode="cell">


                        <p:column headerText="Test Scenario and Test Cases">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tree1.testCaseName}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Execution Order">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tree1.testCaseExecNo}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:treeTable>
```

Output is displayed in attached image.
In output, Login-1 is child for LOGIN. when i print in console, I am getting correctly however when i print in xthml it display parent value from child itself.

Here is the console output:

```
============LOGIN=================
Scenario Name (ROWKEY) :0
TestCase (ROWKEY) :0_0
Scenario Name :LOGIN
TestCases Name : Login-1
   TestScenario ExecNo :1
      TestCase ExecNo :1
TestCase (ROWKEY) :0_1
Scenario Name :LOGIN
TestCases Name : Login-2
   TestScenario ExecNo :1
      TestCase ExecNo :2
TestCase (ROWKEY) :0_2
Scenario Name :LOGIN
TestCases Name : Login-3
   TestScenario ExecNo :1
      TestCase ExecNo :3
TestCase (ROWKEY) :0_3
Scenario Name :LOGIN
TestCases Name : DocumentUpload
   TestScenario ExecNo :1
      TestCase ExecNo :4
```

Comment: You mean it does not display a root tag? I do not see a root tag either in your console... Not with the name login-1. So please explain a little better

Comment: if it's the case that Kukeltje describe you need to show the `root1` you need to make an other node that replace it

Comment: I want to display like this                                                                           
<pre> <code>LOGIN,1
  |__Login-1,1  
  |__Login-2,2  
  |__Login-3,3  
  |__DocumentUpload,4 </code></pre>  
Here, LOGIN is my parent node
Login-1,Login-2,Login-3 are child for LOGIN
1,2,3,4 are another column in table for child node

Comment: `TreeNode parent = new DefaultTreeNode(new TestProcess(tp.getTestScenarioName(), tp.getTestCaseName(), tp.getTestCaseExecNo(), tp.getTestScenarioExecNo()),root1);`  this line is like row only, When u enter data it store as row, so, if you want to print testcase under scenario then in testscenario should be in same column of Testcase.